# Switch from development to production in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I accidently installed Hybris in a development environment on my production machine. How do I switch to production without changing the configurations that I made? Will `ant clean all` resets the configuration?

Comment: I think by default this property is true ->> `development.mode=true`. You can try changing it to false in your local.properties file but not sure its sufficient to switch or not.

Answer (score 1):

`ant clean all` will simply rebuild the platform using the configuration you provided in your `*.properties` files.

To switch to production, I suggest you read the following articles from Hybris Wiki:
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Setting+Up+a+Production+System

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

There is an ant target to set the configurations for the production machines.

```
ant production
```

Find more explantations here:
[Hybris Wiki ant production](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/ant+production+improvements)

To your question about the properties, where have you done the changes? In the *.properties files itself? Normally those changes should not be overwritten. It depends on which kind of properties we are talking about.
Maybe you can check the ant targets to see what will be changed.

Guillaume is not 100% right. There are 'buildcallbacks.xml' files, that also can change properties settings. You have to figure out.